# express-cassandra invalidates uuid when generated uuid package

Tags: cassandra, express-cassandra

I have the following field in my cassandra model:

```
        user: {
            type:"uuid",
            rule:{
                required:true,
            }
        },
```

However, whenever I try to save a data, I get the following error:
`apollo.model.validator.invalidvalue: Invalid Value: "**uuid generated here***" for Field: sender (Type: uuid)`
I have used [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate it

I have tried generating uuid through the package,even hardcoded a uuid but still the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express-cassandra translates datatypes from JS to Cassandra. You may try to use the built-in datatype functions described here:

https://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datatypes/

A built in function to generate uuids is available. If for some reason, another package needs to be used for generating uuids and that generates a uuid as string, then you can convert that using the `models.uuidFromString(str)` function as described in the doc.